# `import using` or `import hiding` in Idris2

Tags: import, syntax, module, namespaces, idris

I'd like to import `Control.App` into a module that refers to `PrimIO.PrimIO` via the unqualified name `PrimIO` in a lot of places. The problem, of course, is that `Control.App` also exports a definition named `PrimIO`. I would like to minimize the damage by importing either **only `App`** or **everything but `PrimIO`** from `Control.App`; i.e. what one would do with `import Control.App (App)` or `import Control.App hiding (PrimIO)` in Haskell.

What is the Idris2 way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think it is implemented yet. See https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/wiki/Contributions-wanted If you want it soon, you would probably have to submit a PR.

Comment: Does `%hide` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @michaelmesser's comment, I was able to get this working with the following:

```
import Control.App
%hide Control.App.PrimIO
```

However, this doesn't give me a good way of explicitly referring to `Control.App.PrimIO` when I *do* need to refer to it.